# Hide or Show elements after picker view elected or text field input

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a form and many UIPickerView and UITextField but I want to:

- Hide some Picker View avec Text Field (here I'm going to use the attribute hidden) but I don't want to have a blank space, so how to do this?
- When I select an item in the Picker View or input something in a Text Field I want to show the hidden item.

How to do this without having blank space?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach :

One approach is to create the pickerview and textField in code and add it to the view.

This approach has the following advantages :

1. Since you are creating the textField only when you need it. Your
   will not be using up valuable memory.
2. You will not have any white space.